# Multithreading implementation in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue

I am in process of implementing messages passing from one thread to another

Thread 1: Callback functions are registered with libraries, on callback, functions are invoked and needs to be send to another thread for processing as it takes time.

Thread 2: Thread to check if any messages are available(preferrednas in queue) and process the same.

Is condition_variable usage with mutex a correct approach to start considering thread 2 processing takes time in which multiple other messages can be added by thread 1?

Answer (score 1):

> Is condition_variable usage with mutex a correct approach to start considering thread 2 processing takes time in which multiple other messages can be added by thread 1?

The question is a bit vague about how a condition variable and mutex would be used, but **yes**, there would definitely be a role for such objects.  The high-level view would be something like this:

- The mutex would protect access to the message queue.  Any read or modification of the queue, by any thread, would be done only while holding the mutex locked.
- The message-processing thread would block on the CV in the event that it became ready to process a new message but the queue was empty.
- The message-generating thread would signal the CV each time it enqueued a new message.

This is exactly a producer / consumer problem, and you can find a lot of information about such problems using that terminology.

But note also that there are multiple message queue implementations already available to serve exactly your purpose ("message queue" is in fact a standard term for these), so you should consider whether you really want to reinvent this wheel.

Answer (score 0):

In general, mutexes are intended to control access between threads; but not great for notifying between threads.

If you design Thread2 to wait on the condition; you can simply process messages as they are received from Thread1.

Here would be a rough implementation

```
void pushFunction
{
   // Obtain the mutex (preferrably scoped lock in boost or c++17)
    std::lock_guard lock(myMutex);
    const bool empty = myQueue.empty();
    myQueue.push(data);
    lock.unlock();

    if(empty)
    {
        conditionVar.notify_one();

    }
}
```

In Thread 2

```
void waitForMessage()
{
    std::lock_guard lock(myMutex);
    while (myQueue.empty())
    {
        conditionVar.wait(lock);
    }

    rxMessage = myQueue.front();
    myQueue.pop();

}
```

It's important to note that the condition can spuriously wake up so it's important to keep it in the 'while empty' loop.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable